# Meteor Signup Code/Link for Facebook Accounts-UI Accounts-Entry

Tags: facebook, meteor, facebook-javascript-sdk, meteorite

I am using the accounts-entry, accounts-ui, accounts-facebook packages and need to have the signup code feature for Facebook.  Anyone successfully done this?

In it's simplest form, I just need a link (that I can dynamically generate) that will grant users access to my app. Then, on my homepage, I need a login button that will only allow those who have already gained access to my app in, and not allow those who don't have access.  So basically a button that grants access to my FB "app" and a button that logs in only those who have access.

Comment: Signup and login are essentially the same thing for the facebook package, except the first time a user logs in, a new user document is created. Other than that, I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: I want a user to be able to be granted access to my app (via a button at a private link) and not allow anyone to be able to login with facebook via a button until they are granted access.  I need to be able to add people to my app programatically and not through the facebook UI manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new collection called "allowedUsers" or something. Add users to this collection who "click the button at a private link".

Then, on the `Accounts.onCreateUser(func)` callback, verify* that the user attempting to login using facebook exists inside the "allowedUsers" collection. If they don't, then just `throw new Meteor.error(500, 'User isn't allowed to sign up through facebook')` (an account is *not* created for the user in this instance).

See the documentation on `Accounts.onCreateUser(func)` for more details.
http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_oncreateuser

*When I say verify, there are multiple ways to do this, but none are infallible to my knowledge. It would be up to you to determine if the person you added to your "allowedUsers" collection is truly the person signing up through facebook.

Comment: sweet! that works.  One last question.  How can I catch the 500 when a user is denied on the client?  I would like to just pop up an alert with a message, rather than it just dying silently.

Comment: @timmyg13 `Meteor.loginWithFacebook()` has a callback function. "Called with no arguments on success, or with a single Error argument on failure."